# Nexus 3.1.0-04 OSS - no artifacts/assets seen in repository/components

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, nexus

I am playing around with Nexus oss 3.1.0-04 OSS. I created a new maven style repository called test and it is proxying from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven; After setting this up, I tried to view the contents of test repository but there is nothing seen. I get a "no component found in repository". Why is this? What is that am missing? If I type the URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven on a browser am able to see all its contents.

Comment: Just a pointer: the functionality to upload artifacts using the UI has been left out in version 3.x: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the local proxy is empty. The best way to get components in is to build a maven project. Of course, make sure your maven settings are configured to point to Nexus - https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/maven.html#maven-sect-single-group).

I should also add, Nexus 3 provides a task for this: Publish Maven indexes
- Maven indexes can be used to download an index of available components to your repo, allowing users connecting to it to use the index to discover components. The task publishes the index for all or a specific Maven repository, hosted, group or proxy. This task will not populate the Browse UI, we intentionally did this so you only see what components and assets are available locally. More on the task here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html